# Scrollbar covering part of web page

Tags: html, browser

I have a web page I am designing which is almost finished. I have an icon to the right of the page which is used to display a menu when clicked, and it is right-aligned to the page. Currently, this icon and everything else on the right hand side of the web page is being covered by the vertical scroll bar. The current behaviour is that it appears only when the mouse curser is hovering over the browser window. I am wondering how it is possible to display the vertical scrollbar within a web page "always", when the page is scrollable (when the page height is greater than the height of the browser window).

Answer (score 1):

For reasons of style, you can always show the vertical, native, web browser scrollbar using the following CSS property `overflow-y : scroll;` (see [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)) to your body :

**CSS**

```
body
{
    overflow-y : scroll;
}
```

[**JSFIddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/g3prnkzm/)